# Eventbrite VenueID is missing

Tags: eventbrite

I am making a call to;

https://www.eventbrite.com/xml/organizer_list_events?id=**MYID**

and getting a collection of event returned. I am integrating this data into an internal event system.

However, periodically I will get a venue without an ID. This means I cant add the venue into the system as I have no way of checking for duplicates before it is imported.

Show the VenueID always be returned? If not, under what circumstances would it not be returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The venue Id will not be returned if there is no venue, e.g. if the event is a webinar / online only event or the venue is not yet chosen